# Android Studio: intermediates directory doesn't get populated

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

I'm using NDK on Android Studio 0.8.9. I've followed [this guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-the-ndk-with-android-studio) where the author is using 0.5.1.
Following his tutorial, he's able to see the generated files into `./app/build/ndk/debug/lib` (around time 3:42 in the video).
However, in my case I see there's an extra directory created by Android Studio, called `intermediates`.  Although the NDK generated libraries are subdirectories of `intermediates`, I don't see them in my project structure.  See image below:

[image: intermediates directory empty]

This is the content of the `intermediates` directory itself (seen from an explorer view):

[image: NDK ExplorerView]

If I add a directory myself with, for instance, only a text file present, then I see that directory under the `build` directory in the `Project` structure.

Is there any filtering present that filters out binary files or something like this?  Or what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you get its solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: Same issue at the moment with Android Studio 2.2.